# Can I apply for an employment visa for Ireland from London while having a Pakistani passport?

Tags: ireland

I am Dr. Waqar Arshad, currently undertaking a masters in UK on a tier 4 visa. I have a now got a job offer in Emergency Medicine in Ireland and currently waiting for the work permit from Ireland, which my employer has already applied for. Since, I hold a Pakistani passport, I am wondering if I am eligible to apply for an employment visa for Ireland from the Embassy of Ireland in London or do I have to travel to Pakistan to apply for the employment visa?

Looking forward to your response.

Many thanks,
Dr. Arshad

Comment: Hi, welcome.  Questions about visas for long-term purposes like working and studying belong at [Expatriates.SE].

Answer (score 1):

At my time, it was Ok to apply for work visa in different country. But I would recommend to call to [the Irish Embassy in London](https://www.dfa.ie/irish-embassy/great-britain/contact-us/) to confirm.

Comment: Based on http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/Employment%20(Permits%20etc.) you can apply online from the UK.

Comment: Yes, but the question is about another problem. Immigration and work visas may have limitations of issuing. For an example, US work and immigration visas may be issued in country of applicant citizenship.